# Magento 2: All Quote details in view source. Does it cause a security issue?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, security

In Magento 2, all the quote, item, payment method, totals details loaded in view source and in `window.checkoutConfig` Js global variable.

Does it cause a security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further clarify why this is **not** a security issue:

- This is data that can be displayed in the checkout or in the mini cart, so it has to be somewhere in the source.
- If it's in a global JavaScript variable `checkoutConfig` or in the DOM, i.e. plain HTML, does not make a difference security wise.
- It is transferred via HTTPS, because your shop runs on HTTPS. If it does not, your site is not secure at all and you should fix that (e.g. with a free letsencrypt certificate)

Answer (score 2):

As long as it does not contain any customer-specific data (such as name, address, payment details) I don't see a security problem here.